# other way how to toggle 2 function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I want to toggle this tweenmax when click `TweenMax.to(con, 1, {height: '200px', ease:Bounce.easeOut});` 
here exactly what I want:

```
function One() {
     TweenMax.to(con, 1, {height: '200px', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
}

function Two() {
     TweenMax.from(con, 1, {height: '200px', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
}

$('.click').toggle(One, Two);
```

con is a div that will animation the height when click
is this posible ? please help

Comment: Have you tried the snippet? What does it do and how does that differ from what you're trying to achieve? Any errors? May be worth noting that jQuery discontinued support for the [`.toggle()` event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) with the release of 1.9.

Comment: So is the question "How do I implement my own version of the [`.toggle()` event binding function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) now that it has been removed from jQuery in v1.9?" (How about looking at the v1.8 code to see how jQuery used to implement it?)

Comment: Why don't you write one function with an if else statement, and toggle a bool?

Answer (score 0):

you could setup a variable to keep track when it was clicked:

this is with using your functions:

```
function One() {
     TweenMax.to(con, 1, {height: '200px', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
}

function Two() {
     TweenMax.from(con, 1, {height: '200px', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
}

var clicked = false;
$(document).on('.click',function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if(clicked === false){
          One();
          clicked = true;
      } else if(clicked === true){
          Two();
          clicked = false;
      }
      return false;
});
```

or use the Tweens right in the click handler:

```
var clicked = false;
$(document).on('.click',function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if(clicked === false){
           TweenMax.to(con, 1, {height: '200px', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
           clicked = true;
      } else if(clicked === true){
           TweenMax.from(con, 1, {height: '200px', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
           clicked = false;
      }
      return false;
});
```